# Defining callback functions for C++in Python

Tags: python, c++, callback, ctypes

I am trying to write a binding to a C++ function that uses callback function. The callback function looks like.

```cpp
typedef enum
{
    CB_Event_TermRegister = 101,
    ...
}enSdkCbType;
typedef enum
{
    TSDK_DEV_TYPE_UNDEF  = 0,
    ...
}enSdkDevType;
typedef struct
{
    enSdkDevType eTermType;
    ...
}TSdkEventTermRegister;

typedef int (CALLBACK* ON_CTS_SDK_CALL_BACK)(enSdkCbType eCbType, LPVOID pParam, DWORD dwSize, int usr_data);
```

Wherein, `enSdkCbType` is a customized `enum` types. `pParam` points to different `struct` based on `eCbType`.
I define this callback in python like this:

```py
from ctypes import *
class enSdkCbType(c_int):
    CB_Event_TermRegister = 101
    ...
class enSdkDevType(c_int):
    TSDK_DEV_TYPE_UNDEF = 0
    ...
class TSdkEventTermRegister(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("eTermType", enSdkDevType),
        ...
    ]

def callback(eCbType, pParam, dwParamLen, usr_data):
    if eCbType == enSdkCbType.CB_Asw_OpenTermAudVid:
        assert dwParamLen == sizeof(TSdkEventTermRegister)
        p = POINTER(TSdkEventTermRegister).from_address(pParam)
        print(p.contents.eTermType)
    return 0

dll = CDLL('my_dll')
CallbackType = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, enSdkCbType, c_void_p, c_ulong)
dll.func(CallbackType(callback))
```

But the `if eCbType == enSdkCbType.CB_Asw_OpenTermAudVid` doesn't work cause the parameters send in this callback is like this:`<enSdkCbType object at 0x01F10F80>, 101, 159492072, 72` and their types are `<class '__main__.enSdkCbType'> <class 'int'> <class 'int'> <class 'int'>` 
Obviously, the format of the parameters is not the same as when I defined them. Besides, it seems that one more parameter(`<enSdkCbType object at 0x01F10F80>`) was send to the callback because by definition, the parameter should be like this `101(eCbType), 159492072(pParam), 72(dwSize), usr_data`.
I don't know where my Python code went wrong, but I can provide a well running C++ version of the callback function.

```cpp
int CALLBACK CSdkMp3Dlg::OnTzlSdkCallback(enSdkCbType eCbType, LPVOID pParam, DWORD dwSize, int usr_data)
{
    switch(eCbType)
    {
        case CB_Event_TermRegister:
        {
            ASSERT(dwSize == sizeof(TSdkEventTermRegister));
            TSdkEventTermRegister * pEventTermRegister = (TSdkEventTermRegister*)pParam;
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main error was the callback was defined incorrectly:

```
CallbackType = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, enSdkCbType, c_void_p, c_ulong)
```

Should be:

```
CALLBACK = ct.WINFUNCTYPE(c_int, enSdkCbType, c_void_p, c_ulong, c_int)
```

The final `c_int` was missing.  Also `WINFUNCTYPE` is the type that matches `CALLBACK` in Windows which is defined as `__stdcall`.  It really only matters on 32-bit builds but should be corrected for portability.

After getting past that there were some errors in the callback.  Below is the C code I tested with and the corrected Python code:

**test.c**

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define API __declspec(dllexport)

typedef enum {
    CB_Event_TermRegister = 101,
} enSdkCbType;

typedef enum {
    TSDK_DEV_TYPE_UNDEF  = 0,
} enSdkDevType;

typedef struct {
    enSdkDevType eTermType;
} TSdkEventTermRegister;

typedef int (CALLBACK* ON_CTS_SDK_CALL_BACK)(enSdkCbType eCbType, LPVOID pParam, DWORD dwSize, int usr_data);

API void func(ON_CTS_SDK_CALL_BACK cb) {
    TSdkEventTermRegister t = {5};
    cb(CB_Event_TermRegister, &t, sizeof t, 0);
}
```

**test.py**

```py
import ctypes as ct
import ctypes.wintypes as w  # Defines Windows types like LPVOID and DWORD
                             # for closer matching of types as documented.
class enSdkCbType(ct.c_int):
    CB_Event_TermRegister = 101

class enSdkDevType(ct.c_int):
    TSDK_DEV_TYPE_UNDEF = 0

class TSdkEventTermRegister(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = ("eTermType", enSdkDevType),

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
CALLBACK = ct.WINFUNCTYPE(ct.c_int, enSdkCbType, w.LPVOID, w.DWORD, ct.c_int)
# Good practice to explicitly declare function arguments and return type.
dll.func.argtypes = CALLBACK,
dll.func.restype = None

# This decorator means "callback = CALLBACK(callback)" so
# the function can be directly passed without wrapping it
# each time.  Also safer if the callback is stored by the
# C code for later use, as wrapping it when called means
# the wrapper is destroyed when the call returns.
# It's not needed in this case, but another good practice.
@CALLBACK
def callback(eCbType, pParam, dwParamLen, usr_data):
    # Get the value as a Python integer otherwise it doesn't
    # match the type being compared to.
    if eCbType.value == enSdkCbType.CB_Event_TermRegister:
        assert dwParamLen == ct.sizeof(TSdkEventTermRegister)
        # The address is of the structure, not a pointer to structure.
        p = TSdkEventTermRegister.from_address(pParam)
        print(p.eTermType.value)
    return 0

dll.func(callback)
```

Output:

```
5
```

Comment: It works! Can I define this callback function inside a class? So that I can pass informations to my class while the function is called. I am trying to do something like this `def callback(self, eCbType, pParam, dwParamLen, usr_data):`, but the process exited with code -1073741819 (0xC0000005). Or should I define the callback function as a class and override  it's `__call__` function?

Comment: I have a java demo using this dll. They define this callback function as a class and implement target business logic in `callback.invoke` and the class `callback` extends `win32.StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback`